# Choosing number of points in Create Fishnet using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.5, vector-grid

Is there a way of getting the analysis "create fishnet" to generate a grid of x number of points in ModelBuilder?

For example, I wish to generate a grid consisting of for example 80 points within a polygon (see picture).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per its documented [Syntax](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm#GUID-2D4D98B7-5ECA-4986-98CA-827C6D824DC5) it is easy to use the Create Fishnet tool to create a fishnet of 80 label points by making:

```
number_rows * number_columns = 80
```

However, also as per its documented [Syntax](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm#GUID-2D4D98B7-5ECA-4986-98CA-827C6D824DC5), there is no option to provide a clipping/selecting polygon that restricts creation of label points within its boundary.

As a workaround you could decrease/increase the distance(s) between fishnet points until, when clipped with your polygon, they number exactly 80.  To automate that process would require using ArcPy (with a `for` loop) or a ModelBuilder model (with an iterator).